# force ssl with .htaccess while rewriting addresses

Tags: .htaccess

I am currently using this .htaccess to redirect all the requests for pages with a directory to my index.php

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|cas)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /seattle/index.php/$1 [L]
```

And this works just fine and produces urls that hide the index.php, and I have code in index.php that makes urls clean looking.

But now I need to force pages to connect via ssl, so I tried

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|cas)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/seattle/index.php/$1 [L]
```

and it works to force ssl, but now it also forces the url to include the index.php:

```
https://example.com/seattle/index.php/pagename
```

instead of what I want

```
https://example.com/seattle/pagename
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change protocol (HTTP -> HTTPS) and/or domain name (`www.example.com` -> `example.com`) the proper redirect ("301 Permanent Redirect" or "302 Found/Temp Redirect") is required.

Therefore you cannot combine rewrite and redirect and still showing original URL. It has to be 2 different rules and the one for changing protocol/domain should be listed first. For example:

```
RewriteEngine on

# force HTTPS for all URLs
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteRule . https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# other rewrite rules
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|cas)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /seattle/index.php/$1 [L]
```

The rule I have added will redirect **ALL** HTTP URLs to HTTPS. If you need only some of them to be redirected -- add appropriate conditions via additional `RewriteCond` line(s).

The `%{HTTPS}` is the most common and kind of "proper" way of checking if SSL is ON or OFF (but it is all depending on your specific circumstances and server config). When checking against `%{HTTPS}` you are safe against situation when your site is running on non-standard port (other than 80). You can use `%{SERVER_PORT} =80` instead (will work for majority of cases).

With the above rules the rewrite for `http://example.com/seattle/pagename` will occur in 2 steps:

1. 301 Redirect to `https://example.com/seattle/pagename`
2. Rewrite (internal redirect) to `/seattle/index.php/pagename`